# Conform to CBCentralManagerDelegate Protocol

Tags: swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbcentralmanager

I am trying to implement a BLEHandler.

This is my code:

```
import CoreBluetooth

class BLEHandler : NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    override init() {
        super.init()

    }

    func cenrealManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!)
    {
        switch (central.state)
        {
        case . unsupported:
            print("BLE is unsupported")
        case.unauthorized:
            print("BLE is unauthorised")
        case.unknown:
            print("BLE is unknown")
        case.resetting:
            print("BLE is resetting")
        case.poweredOff:
            print("BLE is powered off")
        case.poweredOn:
            print("BLE is powered on")
        default:
            print("BLE default")
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error: 
"Type 'BLEHandler' does not conform to protocol 'CBCentralManagerDelegate'"

I have the 'centralManagerDidUpdateState' method so I don't know what I've missed etc.

Answer (score 3):

Method name is misspelled. Not `cenrealManagerDidUpdateState`, it should be [centralManagerDidUpdateState](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518888-centralmanagerdidupdatestate)

Try with...

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)
{

}
```